# C++ design pattern - member-only class

Tags: c++, design-patterns, singleton

I want a class that can only be instantiated as a member of another class.

Id est:

```
class A
{
  public:
    A() :
      member_()
      {};
    void letBSayHi() { member_.sayHi(); }
  private:
    B   member_;
};
class B
{
  public:
    void sayHi() { printf("hola!"); }
};
```

thus:

```
A alpha;           // valid
alpha.letBSayHi(); // # hola!
B beta;            // invalid
beta.sayHi();      // impossible
```

The singleton pattern obviously wouldn't work, as I want one instance of class `B` for every instance of class `A`. But any instantiation of class `B` other than as a class `A`-member should be prohibited.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make `B` a private nested class of `A`:

```
class A {
public:
  void letBSayHi() { member_.sayHi(); }
private:
  class B {
  public:
    void sayHi() { std::cout << "hola!"; }
  };

  B member_;
};
```

**Addendum re: comment:** The implementation can be separated from the declaration like this:

Header:

```
class A {
public:
  void letBSayHi();
private:
  class B {
  public:
    void sayHi();
  };

  B member_;
};
```

Source file:

```
void A::letBSayHi() { member_.sayHi(); }
void A::B::sayHi() { std::cout << "hola!\n"; }
//   ^^^^-- interesting part here
```

Comment: Righto! Did not know that you could declare nested classes. Thanks!

Comment: Hm. Is it still possible to define the class in a separate file? So I still have a `.hpp` and a `.cpp` file?

Comment: Yes, just define the member functions of `A::B` with `A::B::functionname` in the source file. I edited in the code for this example.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you want to include, why not?

```html
class A {
#include "B.hpp"
...
};
```